# Answer key vs key answer?

Tags: phrases, expressions

AFAIK, and as I do use, "answer key" is the one I always see natives using. But there are some people around me who use "key answer" and I wonder if that is also a true way of carrying the same meaning? I've to say that I'm not a native English speaker and same about them. Any help could be appreciated...

Comment: What is the context??

Comment: @HotLicks, my English teacher asked us (her students) to do the pieces of homework he had given us. Then said "you have two hours to do them until I send you the "key answer" (without "S")". I decided to come ask you guys to see if there is something behind it that I'm not aware of...

Comment: It sounds like she meant "answer key", but it would depend on the nature of the homework.

Comment: 'answer key' is at least a strong collocation, probably a compound noun defined in reliable dictionaries. 'Key answer' is at most a weakish collocation.

Answer (score 2):

An *answer key* is a key to the answers (to a test or exercise). It's usually a copy of the test or exercise with the instructor's idea of the best possible answers written in.

A *key answer* is an answer that is key. That is, it's the most important of several possible answers to a question. Alternatively, it could be the answer to a question, as given in the answer key.

Comment: So, in my case, if my teacher requires me to do some kind of homework assignment, and then wants to check them, there should be an answer key, not a key answer...

Comment: @AmirF, yes, at least as the term was used in California when I was in school (30 years ago).